# Access first element in a os.scandir

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using `os.scandir` for getting the list of files in a folder:

```
img_list2 = os.scandir('/home/shared/test')
```

I want to get the first element.

I am trying `img_list2.next()`

```
>>> img_list2.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'posix.ScandirIterator' object has no attribute 'next'
```

So I tried:

```
>>> filt = list(img_list2)
>>> type(filt)
<class 'list'>
>>> globals()['filt']
[<DirEntry 'panaroma00010.jpg'>, <DirEntry 'panaroma00014.jpg'>, <DirEntry 'panaroma00004.jpg'>, <DirEntry 'panaroma00013.jpg'>, <DirEntry 'panaroma00007.jpg'>, <DirEntry 'panaroma00011.jpg'>, <DirEntry 'panaroma00012.jpg'>, <DirEntry 'panaroma00006.jpg'>, <DirEntry 'panaroma00009.jpg'>, <DirEntry 'panaroma00001.jpg'>, <DirEntry 'panaroma00003.jpg'>, <DirEntry 'panaroma00005.jpg'>, <DirEntry 'panaroma00002.jpg'>, <DirEntry 'panaroma00008.jpg'>]
>>> filt[1]
<DirEntry 'panaroma00014.jpg'>
>>>
```

So just like in list we can get the first element value, can we get it from `os.scandir`?

Comment: In addition to the answers below, here is the docs for Iterator in Python 3: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types. It says that Iterators only have the 'magic' functions `__iter__` and `__next__`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`os.scandir()` returns an iterator containing the directory entries for a given path, see `help(os.scandir)`:

```
scandir(...)
    scandir(path='.') -> iterator of DirEntry objects for given path
```

To get a value from it call the built-in `next` on it:

```
next(img_list2)
```

This will return values from the iterator until it is exhausted (and `StopIteration` is raised).

You can also wrap it in a `list` call which create a `list` out of all entries and make it indexable but if you only require the first element that is overkill.

`iterator.next()` was removed as of `Python 3.0` with [`PEP 3114`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114/); a dunder `iterator.__next__()` method replaced it along with the built-in `next()` that calls it.

Comment: how to make a list with indexable entries

Comment: you necessarily must pass `img_list2` in `list()` and then you can index it, i.e `img_list3 = list(img_list2)`.

Comment: Also in jinja2 code of my django project, i tried to use next(img_list2).path . its says error `django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '(img_list2).path' from 'next(img_list2).path'
[13/Sep/2016 23:21:38] "GET /gallery/ HTTP/1.1" 500 130929
`

Comment: Calling `list` on the iterator will make it a list, `list` objects don't have a path attribute. `list(img_list2)[0].path` would work, as would `next(img_list2).path`.

Comment: No i am sending the interator img_list2 to the template. `return render(request,'blog/gallery.html', {'img_list2':img_list2})`

Comment: `next(img_list2).path` is not working when used in the jinja code in my html template

Comment: I can't see the code so I can't reason as to why that happens; I'd suggest you ask another question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476401/django-pythons-os-scandir-next-method-not-working-inside-jinja2-code (added as new question)

Answer (score 1):

[`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) would give you the next item from the `img_list2` iterator:

```
next(img_list2)
```