# Django: pythons os.scandir next() method not working inside template

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have the following code in the views.py

```
def gallery(request):
    import os, sys
    img_list2 = os.scandir('/home/shared/testing')
    return render(request,'blog/gallery.html', {'images2':img_list2})
```

It is sending the iterator img_list2 to the template gallery.html

My gallery.html is as follows

```
<div>
<p>{{ next(images2).path }}</p>    
</div>
```

I am just testing the next() method works or not.

it says

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '(images2).path' from 'next(images2).path'
[13/Sep/2016 23:21:38] "GET /gallery/ HTTP/1.1" 500 13092
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not using Jinja2; you're using the Django template language, where it's invalid syntax to call functions with parameters.

Comment: As I said, that syntax is not valid in Django templates.

Comment: I hope i can use {{ }} to put the values of a variable

Comment: A variable, yes. Not a function call with parameters.

Comment: Ok. can you edit you answer mentioning "Not a function call with parameters"